# Get id of next and previous record in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

I want to display links of first and previous record. I use following code but it returns empty.

```
$neighbors = $this->names->find('neighbors', array('conditions'=>array('names.Id'=>12),'limit'=>1));
```

This is my working code below, which returns data for the current record

```
$this->set("names", $this->names->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('names.Id'=>$id))));
```

How can I achieve this. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try by removing limit $neighbors = $this->names->find('neighbors', array('conditions'=>array('names.Id'=>12)));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As docs says http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html, 
you need to do like this

```
$neighbors = $this->names->find(
        'neighbors',
        array('field' => 'Id', 'value' => 12)
    );
```

Comment: +1. worth highlighting that the code in the question will result in ([amongst other queries](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3141)) `WHERE Id = 12 AND Id < 12` - which will obviously result in 0 rows. Specifying a limit of one would also, obviously, have returned at most one of the neighbours.

Comment: I couldn't see `find('neighbors')` sadly in CakePHP 3, [among its finder types listed in the doc.](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data) I had to use a `find('all')` with 
  `'conditions' => [ 'id < ' . $id], 'order' => 'id DESC'` and `first()` to get the previous record. Wonder if there's a better way.